# Windows 10 UWP - detect if the current internet connection is Wifi or Cellular?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, uwp, windows-10-mobile

In Windows 10 UWP app how do I detect if the current internet connection is Wifi or Cellular?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In UWP you can check network connectivity using the IsWlanConnectionProfile or IsWwanConnectionProfile properties.

An example would be:

```
var temp = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();

if (temp.IsWlanConnectionProfile)
{
     // its wireless
}else if (temp.IsWwanConnectionProfile)
{
     // its mobile
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: You should check also if `temp` is `null`.

Answer (score 10):

Other than just getting the connectivity (that others have mentioned) you can also handle metered connections better.

[How to manage metered network cost constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/JJ835821(v=win.10).aspx)

```
switch (connectionCost.NetworkCostType)
{
    case NetworkCostType.Unrestricted:
        //
        break;
    case NetworkCostType.Fixed:
        //
        break;
    case NetworkCostType.Variable:
        //
        break;
    case NetworkCostType.Unknown:
        //
        break;
    default:
        //
        break;
}
```

See the [networking demo at GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/714722f53c3ae270f634f54cb2740411f6b11032/Samples/MobileBroadband/cs/GetConnectionProfiles.xaml.cs).

```
if (connectionCost.Roaming || connectionCost.OverDataLimit)
{
    Cost = NetworkCost.OptIn;
    Reason = connectionCost.Roaming
        ? "Connection is roaming; using the connection may result in additional charge."
        : "Connection has exceeded the usage cap limit.";
}
else if (connectionCost.NetworkCostType == NetworkCostType.Fixed
    || connectionCost.NetworkCostType == NetworkCostType.Variable)
{
    Cost = NetworkCost.Conservative;
    Reason = connectionCost.NetworkCostType == NetworkCostType.Fixed
        ? "Connection has limited allowed usage."
        : "Connection is charged based on usage. ";
}
else
{
    Cost = NetworkCost.Normal;
    Reason = connectionCost.NetworkCostType == NetworkCostType.Unknown
        ? "Connection is unknown"
        : "Connection cost is unrestricted";
}
```