# sync with local db and azure mobile service

Tags: c#, windows, azure, azure-mobile-services, uwp

I am developing a Windows 10 application which should download data up to 30mb data from mobile service(written)  and store it in local db. This should be performed every day when connected to WIFI network.

Can anyone help me out with this scenario.

Thanks in advance

Trilok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite definitely doable with Azure Mobile Apps.

Use [Azure Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/app-service/mobile/) to write the main backend.  You can start with the QuickStart backend and then modify for your particular scenario.  Just follow the QuickStart tutorial for offline sync (and probably authentication).  I've produced a [QuickStart for Windows 10 UWP](https://github.com/adrianhall/quickstarts/tree/master/QuickStart.UWP).  In your Windows 10 application, only call the UpdateAsync() method when you are on Wifi.  You can look at [this question to detect wifi vs. cellular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845625/windows-10-uwp-detect-if-the-current-internet-connection-is-wifi-or-cellular).